# JavaScript regex path format

Tags: javascript, regex

Sorry for a really newbie question regarding to regex, how do you specify sub directories with regex, here’s what I know how to do it for the root directory what I want to achieve is how to do it for the sub directories for example app directory and asset directory any help would be grateful here are what I have I am using it in JavaScript

```
regex="\.(htm|html|js|css)$
```

Thanks advance

Comment: Not exactly sure what you want here. Please refer to [how do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Step back and read your question as if you have no preconceived knowledge for the task you're trying to accomplish. It seems very broad.

Comment: You need to back up and tell us what you're trying to accomplish with this regex and why.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the answer you want, but you can use a regex like this:

`.\/src\/app\/([a-zA-Z0-9]+.(htm|html|css|js))`

or something to select all files in a sub directory, like:

```
./src/app/hello.html
./src/app/123.js
./src/app/hello123.css
```

just edit the regex to get the subdirectories you need as you see fit.

---

[Extension based on OP's comment]

To select multiple subdirectories, maybe just something like:

`.\/src\/(app|asset)\/([a-zA-Z0-9]+.(htm|html|css|js))`

would work for the file directories "app" and "asset" like this:

```
./src/app/hello.html
./src/app/123.js
./src/app/hello123.css
./src/asset/hello.html
./src/asset/123.js
```

but not some other file directory "blabla" e.g. `./src/blabla/hello123.css`

Comment: Thanks that’s what I want, if I need to do multiple directories would I have to do it in different line or is there a way to do it in one line

Comment: I've added an improvement to this answer, hope it helps to solve your problem! So you could do it in 1 line, but it gets a bit hard to read as the RegEx gets longer and longer. Maybe you'd like to make different RegEx patterns for the different subdirectories you have just to make it easier to maintain this piece of code in the future :)